# Using Qt classes natively in an Android application

Tags: qt

The Android application I am about to work on has the UI in Java and the non-UI functionality in C++ that would be accessed via JNI. The C++ code uses some non-UI Qt classes. I am thinking I will spawn a thread in `JNI_OnLoad`that essentially will instantiate and run `QCoreApplication`. Any subsequent JNI call will simply post an event to this thread. Is this possible? Regards.

Comment: I think it is. Honestly, your question is not really a question. Why don't you just test it by building a sample project?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is definitely possible but a bit more difficult than it seems initially.

If you build your app end to end in Qt there's a lot of functionality you get for free from their framework that allows it to run on Android and a lot of that functionality/plumbing is wrapped up in their UI.  So if you're not using their UI there's extra work that you need to do.

On Android their UI framework basically creates a native Activity and then uses that activity as a wrapper for the app.  If you look at the low-level source for their UI thats what's happening on Android and it's what allows the Qt app to access local resources, the network, OS facilities, etc.

Without the Activity wrapper, your app will only be able to do simple, in-memory operations that require no OS, file system, or network access and also won't be able to make use of other Qt libraries(eg Qt5Sql, Qt5Core, etc).

Here's what we had to do to make this work in our java app:

1. Create a proxy wrapper Activity for Qt to use that shares the base
   context of your app.
2. Create a QtActivityDelegate.
3. Set the proxy activity and delegate using the native Qt android
   libraries.  eg QtNavite.setActivity.
4. Instantiate and set a DexClassLoader using the same native Qt android libraries.
5. Load any Qt libraries using System.loadLibrary(..).  Please note that the libraries need to be present on the file system already. This part was a big pain for us.

For your Qt Code, make sure you have proper wrappers written so that they can be used via jni.  We ended up using swig to auto-generate java wrappers for our code.
You can find out more about swig here: http://swig.org/

After all that you should be able to use your Qt class/library from within a native Android app.

Painful but definitely possible!